# Django : 'str' object has no attribute 'objects' in create_user

Tags: django, django-forms, django-users

This is my registration code

```
 def registration_with_js_form(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        first_name=request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name=request.POST.get('last_name')
        mobile_number=request.POST.get('mobile_number')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        confirm_password=request.POST.get('confirm_password')
        checkbox=request.POST.get('checkbox')

        if checkbox==False:
            """Redirect with error message"""
            return redirect('home')


        if(password!=confirm_password):
            """Redirect with error message"""
            return redirect('home')


        code =''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase , k=3))
        random_str=str(random.randint(10,99))+str(code)
        username_=first_name+"@"+random_str
        print(username_)


        curr_user=Account.objects.create_user(email=email,username=username_,
                                    password=password)
        curr_user.phone_number=mobile_number
        curr_user.first_name=first_name
        curr_user.last_name=last_name
        curr_user.save()

        """Redirect with success message"""
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request,'main/index.html')
```

And this is my Abstract user model

[image]

ANd IT shows error like this

[image]

And all of the fields are field with the appropriate data that I filled in that form
if I print all of these

```
print([first_name,last_name,mobile_number,email,password,confirm_password,checkbox])
OutPut ['Samir', 'Patil', '1234567890', 'm@gmail.com', '123', '123', 'on']
```

Please Help.!

Comment: Are you/do you want to import Account?

Comment: Please show the import statement for `Account` in your view. It seems that there might be a problem there because according to the error message your variable `Account` holds a string and not a model class.